# Entendendo "findAllByXXXXContainingIgnoreCase"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot

Eu estou começando a aprender spring boot / java, e estamos modelando um banco de dados simples de rede social/blog, com 3 tabelas, postagens, temas, e usuários. Quando criamos o "Repository" das tabelas, extendemos jpa, mas é preciso ainda adicionar um método à interface, um método para fazer uma busca em títulos/descrições por palavras usadas, como se fosse um "like %palavra%" do sql, e então retornar todos os itens que que contém aquela palavra em seu titulo/descrição. Chamamos esse método de "findAllByDescricaoContainingIgnoreCase" para fazer a busca em descrição, e "findAllByTituloContainingIgnoreCase" para fazer a busca em titulos.

Nós adicionamos ele como método público, sem corpo(código), na interface "PostagemRepository" e  na interface "TemaRepository". Eu imaginava que teríamos que implementar ele, adicionando seu corpo/código, mas a minha surpresa quando, mesmo ele não não tendo corpo, ele funciona normalmente na Controller(!). Minha pergunta é como esse método funciona, mesmo sem termos adicionado nenhum código para ele... Seguem os códigos, agradeço desde já por qualquer ajuda!

```
//Código na Repository:
@Repository
public interface PostagemRepository extends JpaRepository<Postagem, Long>{

public List<Postagem> findAllByTituloContainingIgnoreCase (String titulo);
    
}

//Código na Controller:
public class PostagemController {

    @Autowired
    private PostagemRepository repository;
    
    @GetMapping("/titulo/{titulo}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Postagem>> getByTitulo(@PathVariable String titulo) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(repository.findAllByTituloContainingIgnoreCase(titulo));
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse caso você está usando Query Methods, o Spring monta as queries baseadas em um padrão de palavras e nos atributos da entidade(classe) que você declarou na repository.
Não encontrei materiais bons em português, mas você pode dar uma olhada na Doc do próprio Spring. [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) e [Keywords do Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)

Comment: Opa, vou dar uma olhada nessas documentações aí, muito obrigado!

Comment: @YuriSilva caso tenha resolvido o problema da sua questão com essa resposta marque ela como aceita

Answer (score -4):

Não sei exatamente te responder, porém se não me engano ele usa reflection para se adaptar aos prefixos e montar as query's.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer publicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), mas, até lá, escreva apenas respostas que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/371741)